# django load object name by language

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.7

I have models defined like that

```
class Foo(Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key = True)
    code = CharField(blank = False, unique = False, max_length =  64)

class FooName(Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key = True)
    foo = ForeignKey(Foo, blank = False, related_name = '+')
    language = CharField(blank = False, max_length = 16)
    value = CharField(blank = False, max_length = 256)

class Bar(Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key = True)
    foo = ForeignKey(Foo, blank = False, related_name = '+')
```

So, for 'foo' table like

```
{ 1, 'apple' },
{ 1, 'pear' }
```

I have 'fooname' table like

```
{ 1, 1, 'en', 'Apple'},
{ 2, 1, 'fr', 'Pomme'},
{ 3, 2, 'en', 'Pear'},
{ 4, 2, 'fr', 'Poire'}
```

And, of course I have request.LANGUAGE set to something meaningful.

The question is: How can I have name property on Foo model dynamically evaluated to localized name, i.e something like

```
self.name = FooName.objects.get(foo = self, language = request.LANGUAGE)
```

but without passing request object explicitly?

I mean, if I have collection of Bar I want to write something like

```
for bar in Bar.objects.filter(...):
    fn = bar.foo.name
```

No complex language matching (use 'en' for 'en-US') or fallback (use 'en-US' if no value for current language) logic is required.

Comment: Do you need to populate some dropdown list using these values? If so,you can make this query in views and populate the form by setting queryset attribute.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal Not only dropdowns, but lists, tables or even single items

Answer (score 0):

Why cannot you do this?

```
for bar in Bar.objects.filter(...):
    fn = FooName.objects.get(foo=bar.foo, language=request.LANGUAGE).value
```

Comment: Because I cannot do this in template and I do not want to do this in form.

Comment: @adontz and why can't you do this in views?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal because it means that View should be aware of what fields (not objects) template of form requires. This increases coupling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in template you need a custom template tag. In this you have access to the request object. You can extract the language and pass it to a model instance method.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models


class Foo(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=64)

    def get_name(self, language_code):
        return self.foo_set.filter(language=language).get()

class FooName(Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

# templatetages/mytags.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def resolve_foo_name(context, foo_object):
    return foo_object.get_name(context.LANGUAGE)


# template.html
{% load mytags %}
{% resolve_foo_name foo_object %}
```